# Python `inspect.stack()` returns FrameInfo objects with missing `code_context` at the REPL

Tags: python, introspection

When using Python's REPL/interactive prompt, the objects returned by `inspect.stack()` always have `.code_context` set to `None`.

The same code executed from within a .py file returns the code line by line in a stack trace as expected.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> print(inspect.stack()[0].code_context)
None
```

same code executed within a .py file prints:

`['print(inspect.stack()[0].code_context)\n']`

Comment: The only way that the `inspect` module can display source code is if the code came from a file that it can access.  Source typed at an interactive prompt is discarded as soon as it is parsed, there's simply no way for `inspect` to access it.

Comment: I was afraid of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting comment from @jasonharper as the answer here. Thanks!

> The only way that the `inspect` module can display source code is if the code came from a file that it can access. Source typed at an interactive prompt is discarded as soon as it is parsed, there's simply no way for `inspect` to access it. – @jasonharper